# How to parse an internal json part from log4j record using egrok

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok, filebeat, kibana-5

This is my input log4j line being shipped by filebeat

```
2017-07-02 08:46:28,702 INFO  com.company.service.EventService - Consumed event: {
  "details": {
    "A": 10,
    "B": "EUR"
  },
  "eventId": "45YHJAIBpPeExHtskhqRbTDI9oEk2wPl",
  "eventArrivalTime": "2017-07-02T08:46:28.700Z"
}
```

I managed to remove `2017-07-02 08:46:28,702 INFO part` (mapped it into field: `msgbody`) and now im trying to parse the json part from it into fields on kibana.

I want to index into kibana the fields inside the event: {..} e.g eventId details

this is what i have done so far and I have no idea how to extract this json

```
filter {
  if [type] == "log" {
    grok {
       match => {
        "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:logdate} %{LOGLEVEL:loglevel} %{GREEDYDATA:msgbody}"
      }
      add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
      add_field => [ "received_from", "%{host}" ]
    }
    date {
      match => ["logdate", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS", "ISO8601"]
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: please have a look at updated answer

Answer (score 0):

`msgbody` is mapped using `GREEDYDATA` in your filter, which wouldn't match a new line. This means your `msgbody` will only match `com.company.service.EventService - Consumed event: {`

You need to map everything after `INFO` till `},` into a separate field, which can be matched using,

```
(?m)%{DATA:msgbody}\},
```

It will match,

```
"msgbody": [
    [
      "  com.company.service.EventService - Consumed event: {\n  "details": {\n    "A": 10,\n    "B": "EUR"\n  "
    ]
  ]
```

The rest of the data, i.e,

```
  "eventId": "45YHJAIBpPeExHtskhqRbTDI9oEk2wPl",
  "eventArrivalTime": "2017-07-02T08:46:28.700Z"
```

needs to be matched in its own block so that it can then be filtered using a `json` filter,

```
%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:logdate} %{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}(?m)%{DATA:msgbody}\},%{GREEDYDATA:json}
```

This will produce,

```
  "msgbody": [
    [
      "  com.company.service.EventService - Consumed event: {\n  "details": {\n    "A": 10,\n    "B": "EUR"\n  "
    ]
  ],
  "json": [
    [
      "\n  "eventId": "45YHJAIBpPeExHtskhqRbTDI9oEk2wPl",\n  "eventArrivalTime": "2017-07-02T08:46:28.700Z"\n}"
    ]
  ]
```

Now we have json fields into a new field called `json`.

json filter can be then applied on it as follows,

```
json{
    source => "json"
    target => "parsed_json"
}
```

hope this helps